# TypeError at /profile/edit_profile/ profile_edit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

Tags: python, django

Пишу социальную сеть. При попытке отредактировать профиль выходит ошибка выше. Кто-то может, пожалуйста, объяснить что не так с моим кодом?

```
@login_required
def profile_edit(request, username):
    username = get_object_or_404(User, author=username)
    if request.username != post.author:
        return redirect('blog:post_detail', username)
    form = PostForm(
        request.POST or None,
        files=request.FILES or None,
        instance=post)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('blog:post_detail', author=username)
    template = 'blog/create.html'
    context = {'form': form, 'post': post}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: Логичный вопрос — откуда должен браться этот самый username?

Comment: Я же обозначаю его в функции, разве нет?

Comment: `def profile_edit(request, username):` — у вас username это входной параметр функции, а ошибка говорит о том, что тот, кто вызывает эту функцию, не передал этот параметр. И откуда должен браться этот username-то?

Comment: Простите, но я действительно не понимаю. Я обозначаю в 3й строке author=username

Comment: В третьей строке вы используете username для поиска в базе, но что такое username и откуда он должен браться?

Comment: Его вводит пользователь при регистрации

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду, что вы хотите использовать username текущего пользователя, значит используйте `request.user.username` и уберите параметр username из функции вообще, потому что в таком случае он абсолютно не нужен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, начнем с того, что ошибка "TypeError: profile_edit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'" означает, что функция `profile_edit()` требует передачи аргумента `username`, но ты вызываешь функцию без этого аргумента.

Предположу, что тебе нужно передать `username` в URL-шаблоне. Убедись, что у тебя есть правильно настроенный URL-шаблон для представления `profile_edit()`, который включает `username` в качестве аргумента.

Например, твой URL-шаблон может выглядеть как-то так:

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('profile/edit/<str:username>/', views.profile_edit, name='profile_edit'),
    # ...
]
```

Получившийся URL-шаблон будет передавать значение `username` в качестве аргумента функции `profile_edit()`

Измени свой код функции `profile_edit()` следующим образом:

```py
@login_required
def profile_edit(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    # ...
```

Затем обнови шаблон с формой редактирования профиля, чтобы в URL-шаблоне использовать аргумент `username`.

Например:

```html
<form action="{% url 'blog:profile_edit' username=request.user.username %}" method="POST">
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```